# problems with pagination in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, pagination

i have a probleme with pagination, i don't see the buttons (1,2,3.....) for ma pagination with this code

```
    <div ng-controller="PaginationDemoCtrl">
    <table class="table">
      <tr ng-repeat="row in data.slice(((currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage), ((currentPage)*itemsPerPage))">
        <td>{{row.name}}</td>
        <td>{{row.id}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
          <select ng-model="viewby" ng-change="setItemsPerPage(viewby)">
    <option>3</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>30</option>
    <option>40</option>
    <option>50</option>
          </select>

    <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()" class="pagination-sm" items-per-page="itemsPerPage"></pagination>
    <pre>The selected page no: {{currentPage}}</pre>
    <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="setPage(3)">Set current page to: 3</button>

    <hr />
    <h4>Pager</h4>
    <pager total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" items-per-page="itemsPerPage"></pager>

    <hr />
    <h4>Limit the maximum visible buttons</h4>
    <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true" items-per-page="itemsPerPage"></pagination>
    <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true" rotate="false" num-pages="numPages" items-per-page="itemsPerPage"></pagination>
    <pre>Page: {{currentPage}} / {{numPages}}</pre>
  </div>
```

i don't understand why ?

i share a plunker, this is for the second table

http://plnkr.co/edit/6qzk1CaeoPYUD1GVudtg?p=preview

if some one can help me please

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `uib-pagination` instead of `pagination`. Also, the directive is only applicable as an attribute, not an element. So, you should consider doing something like this:

```
<ul uib-pagination total-items="totalItems" 
  ng-model="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" 
  class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true" 
  items-per-page="itemsPerPage"></ul>
```

[The documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#pagination) has a good example.